# Is INSERT INTO SELECT vulnerable to SQL injections?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

Say you let users insert their names (or anything into a table) and someone tries a SQL injection but you properly use prepared statements so the query is not affected.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_name) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['user_name']);
```

But now you use that value that was inserted in the `user_name` column and insert it into another table.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO different_table (name) VALUES (
    SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE userId = ?
)");
```

Does `user_name` get treated as a string (assuming a `varchar` datatype) ? In other words, do you only need to prepare the user input when it first gets inserted and comes from the client ?

### Edit

If the value inside `user_name` contains an injection, and now I want to insert this value in another table do I need to first run a `select` in order to get the value and then use it in a prepared statement when I do the insert ? Like so ?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_id = 1");
```

Then

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO another_table (name) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $resultFromFirstQuery['user_name']);
```

Or can I just do something like this ?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO different_table (name) SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE userId = ?");
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO .. VALUES (SELECT ..)` is a stupid thing. There exists immediate `INSERT .. SELECT`. In your case - `INSERT INTO different_table (name) SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE userId = ?`.

Comment: *Is INSERT INTO SELECT vulnerable to SQL injections?* Of course. An injection may save incorrect data which may be used for further attack.

Comment: @Akina So, in that case, should you use 2 separate queries, first select `user_name`, then another one for inserting, and use `bindParam` on `user_name` ?

Comment: @RDU No, you just prevent SQL injection in the same way you do on any query, by using parameters. There's nothing special about this particular construction in terms of injection attacks. As Akina's first comment points out, you can simplify the syntax, but again that doesn't change anything...use prepared statements and parameters and that will make you safe. If you concatenate anything directly into the SQL string then you're potentially in danger. That is true of _any_ SQL statement.

Comment: Why 2 queries? where you have taken this from? `INSERT .. SELECT` is one solid SQL statement. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html - study.

Comment: `In other words, do you only need to prepare the user input when it first gets inserted and comes from the client`...yes.

Comment: @ADyson But if the value inside `user_name` contains an injection (and this value was previously inserted), and now I insert it into a different table using INSERT SELECT (regardless of the syntax) is that safe ? 

If it's not safe, would I not need to use 2 separate queries (I mean 2 separate prepared statements) because how can you use prepared statements on a value that you get from the select ?

Comment: `If the value inside user_name contains an injection, and now I want to insert this value in another table do I need to first run a select in order to get the value and then use it in a prepared statement when I do the insert`... no. The database will not treat it as code. That only happens in situations where you hard-code text into the query which then becomes treated as code (e.g. because it isn't escaped or quoted properly).

Comment: In the insert...select case the DB is getting data out of an existing Db field, so it already knows not to treat that data as code. It never becomes part of the SQL statement.

Comment: @ADyson Ok, I understand, thank you, because the data comes from an existing field, it won't get treated as code, and I assume I can use functions like `CONCAT()`  and such and it would not matter. But Akina said _An injection may save incorrect data which may be used for further attack._  Are there still scenarios where that could be the case ? Also if you want to turn all this into an answer.

Comment: `An injection may save incorrect data which may be used for further attack`... maybe @Akina can clarify further, but I'd expect this could occur if you pulled this data out of the DB, and then re-included it (without parameterisation) in another SQL statement you build from a programming language, and then execute again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would claim that no SQL injection is possible because no SQL statement is getting constructed. In other words:, SQL injection can only happen in the programming language creating the SQL statement, not in the SQL statement itself.

To elaborate: the core of a SQL injection attack is that unchecked user input is *used* to *generate* a SQL statement which goes beyond the original purpose of the user input. For example, if your program does this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email = '{input.email}'"
```

and a user inputs

```
hacker@example.com' OR 1 = 1; --
```

for {input.email}, then the variable `$sql` ends up being

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email = 'hacker@example.com' OR 1 = 1; -- '
```

The security risk now comes from *executing* this unchecked statement on your database.

In your example no SQL is being constructed. If you execute the statement

```
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2
```

there is no point where unchecked user input is being appended to the query string. The result of the `SELECT` may contain input that would be unsafe when considered as SQL, but the values of a text field are never run as statements on the database so whether your table contains `12345` or `hacker@example.com' OR 1 = 1; --` is not relevant.

The only *conceivable* case I could think of would be if your database server had a bug, and having some specific set of bytes in memory at a specific location could cause a memory overflow which then opens up an attack vector. But this is outside of your control and something that a database vendor would presumably fix very quickly; it is also something you can do nothing against and has nothing to do with SQL injection.